# Small Icons and text on 15.10

Tags: nvidia, firefox, fonts, display-resolution

I just installed ubuntu 15.10 on my Asus ux303lb with Nvidia graphics and the resolution is 3200x1800 and everything looked smaller than it should be. Both the apps and text were very small, I managed to fix the size with the apps be increasing the scaling in Display in System Settings, but the text font in Firefox is still small. I have 2 questions is what I did with the scaling actually a solution or just a temporary fix and if so is there an actual solution? And what can I do about the text font being so small in Firefox?

Comment: Have you had a look at the font settings in firefox?

Comment: Yes and it does help out somewhat, but the search and toolbar are still really small the font only affects the web pages I look up

Answer (score 0):

By default, [Firefox sets the size of icons in the toolbar](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/1170143), home button, etc., based on the size set by your system, using a value of `-1.0` on  `layout.css.devPixelsPerPx`.

If you've adjusted the icon sizes in Settings, or with something like Gnome Tweak, this could affect the size of your icons in the Firefox toolbar.

You can oveeride this in advanced preferences:

1. Open an new tab and type `about:config` into the address bar
2. Search for `layout.css.devPixelsPerPx`
3. Change the value from `-1.0` to `1.5` or a size that suits you

Make sure you don't change it to below `1.0`, otherwise the icons could become to small to interact with.